# Conditional fields in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I have a panel code pane that displays this code to show/hide the content if a field, it works great but I want the code to just not display anything if there is no content in %node:field_desc6

---

```
<script language="javascript">
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Show Non-CGD Publications";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Hide Non-CGD Publications";
    }
}
</script>


<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show Non-CGD Publications</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">%node:field_desc6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<script language="javascript">
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Show Non-CGD Publications";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = ""; // here you don't put any text...
    }
}
</script>


<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show Non-CGD Publications</a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">%node:field_desc6</div>
```